How to delete the international language version
The international languages version only show up in the "Keyboard layout"

It doesn't show up on Windows's setting

I also tried the Powershell Method and it doesn't show the international one

I decided to delete the international version because it so annoying when i want to change the language layout, i have to press Windows + Space twice every time

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This question is similar to: How to get rid of US language in Windows 11. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This explains if you delete the Preload registry keys you can also remove it
